# How do I setup prometheus jmx metrics for grabbing all metrics related to socket-server-metrics?

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, jmx

I am trying to setup jmx metrics for a very specific metric that I requires which is
kafka.server / socket-server-metrics / <listener_name> / networkProcessor=.:io-wait-ratio

What patterns should I try to be able to get this specific metrics?

Comment: Do the existing configs not work? https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/main/example_configs/kafka-2_0_0.yml